# JS content not getting loaded in vscode webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Im developing my first vscode extension. trying to create webview and open a webpage inside vscode editor.

Case 1 :
Im using iframe with sandbox attributes. when i tried loading **http** site which runs locally, i can see js content not getting loaded in webview.

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
        'Editor',
        'Editor',
        vscode.ViewColumn.One,
        {
            enableScripts: true
        }
    );

    panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();

    function getWebviewContent() {
        return `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
           <iframe src="http://localhost:8988" sandbox="allow-scripts" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe>
        </body>
        </html>`;
    }
```

Case 2 :

- I also tried opening https site, `https://cssgradient.io/`. In that site also js content is not getting loaded.

Note : No error logs in console.

Can you please let me know if im missing something?

Comment: If you visit  `http://localhost:8988` in a browser, is the script loaded? Also real websites often prevent themselves from being embedded in iframes which may explain why `cssgradient.io` doesn't load

Comment: when i load in browser all js content and script is loading as execpted

Answer (score 0):

If you can check on the console logs (by using the command: `Open Webview Developer Tools`), you may can see some security errors as follows.

> Refused to frame 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Therefore you need to change specific Content Security Policies in-order to load your domain in an iframe.

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

In my case, it works after update `frame-src` CSP policy.